# How to Remove duplicate rows in AG Grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rows, ag-grid

I was experimenting with AG Grid in Angular, and immediately facing a challenge.

[image]

I want to make sure that AG Grid shows unique rows.

Should I iterate over the Grid and remove duplicate rows or check if a row with those values already exists in the Grid?

I was thinking to use a Set for this challenge. I hope to receive some help finding the most efficient solution in code.

**grid-test.component.html**

```
<!-- Button to clear selection -->
<button (click)="clearSelection()">Clear Selection</button>
<!-- AG Grid Angular Component -->
<ag-grid-angular
   style="width: 70%; height: 100%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
   class="ag-theme-alpine"
   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
   [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
   [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
   [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
   [animateRows]="true"
   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
   (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
 ></ag-grid-angular>
```

**grid-test.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { CellClickedEvent, ColDef, GridReadyEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid-test',
  templateUrl: './grid-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid-test.component.css']
})
export class GridTestComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  // Each Column Definition results in one Column.
 public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  { field: 'make'},
  { field: 'model'},
  { field: 'price' }
];

// DefaultColDef sets props common to all Columns
public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
};

// Data that gets displayed in the grid
public rowData$!: Observable<any[]>;

// For accessing the Grid's API
@ViewChild(AgGridAngular) agGrid!: AgGridAngular;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

// Example load data from sever
onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
  this.rowData$ = this.http
    .get<any[]>('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json');
}

// Example of consuming Grid Event
onCellClicked( e: CellClickedEvent): void {
  console.log('cellClicked', e);
}

// Example using Grid's API
clearSelection(): void {
  this.agGrid.api.deselectAll();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches you can take to ensuring there are no duplicate rows that have the same data.

One approach would be to iterate over every row using `api.forEachNode` and keep track if a row already exists.

Another approach would be to create a Set from the current row data and then convert that back into an array. You can see an example of this being implemented in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/weqpX8xlCEQv3C0O?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

```
  onBtnRemove() {
    const rowDataSlash = new Set(
      this.rowData.map((row) => row.make + '/' + row.model + '/' + row.price)
    );
    
    const newRowData = Array.from(rowDataSlash).map((row) => {
      const rowParts = row.split('/');
      return { make: rowParts[0], model: rowParts[1], price: rowParts[2] };
    });
    this.rowData = newRowData;
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make apply this on my code snippet?

Comment: This is how you could achieve the same result with rxjs observables: https://plnkr.co/edit/4aJDymX6XmZ5EicJ?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts